# Selenium Webdriver - Best way to handle redirected URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a scenario - when I click a button(**abcB**) on my test url(http://example.com), it will be redirected to different url(http://yourname.xyz) and there when I click a button(**xyzB**), it will come back to my usual test url(http://example.com) and does performs further function. Please let me know how I could do this Selenium Webdriver.

Comment: Show us your tried code.

Comment: Where are you facing the error/issue? Error Stack Trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple and straight forward task. I am writing some pseudo code, because you didn't share any html code for reference. please use the below code and try.

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("<your xpath reference of button in first page>").click(); //to click on the button, and will navigate to target page
driver.getTitle();// to get the title to ensure you are in the correct page
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("<your xpath reference of button in second page>").click();
driver.getTitle();// to get the title to ensure that the browser is navigated back
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Since url would change, I thought we would need to handle it differently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand not wrong you scenario is like this

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("Your xpath").click();
//wait for few second for loading site
    for (String windows : wd.getWindowHandles()) {

                wd.switchTo().window(windows);

                if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith(Link + "xyz.com")) {

                //Your Operation
                   }
                if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith(Link+"yzx.com")) {
    //Your Operation
                    }


            }
```

Here What I did, I click on redirect link.And wait for few second for site load.After redirection, i return desire tab link start with, where you can give other condition also!!

> Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

First click on the second URL locator match the title and come back to first URL do the same thing here by this you can  handle redirected URL

You can try this sample example

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  //Go to first URL and click on Download menu
  driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menu_download']")).click();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 //Click on  the Source code to redirect to second URL    
   WebElement sourceCode=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mainContent']/p[1]/a[2]"));
 sourceCode.click();

//Get the title of SecondURL and match
 String SecondUrl= driver.getTitle();
if(SecondUrl.contains("GitHub - SeleniumHQ/selenium: A browser automation framework and ecosystem."))
 {
System.out.println("welcome to second URL");
 }
//come back to First URL by click on link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'http://seleniumhq.org')]")).click();

//Get the title of FirstURL and match
 String FirstUrl= driver.getTitle();;
if(FirstUrl.contains("Selenium - Web Browser Automation"))
{
 System.out.println("welcome to First URL");
}
```